Make popup view with horizontal list icons to show above recycler view item,

I need to create a reaction popup like this image. I have tried some basics of the popup menu it won't let me show it at the proper location on the screen, The requirement is very simple. When Long taps on the item of recycler view, It shows a popup like this. On the above of selected recycler view item.
I have tried with a popup window along with custom layouts, Now the popup is showing with a reactions list, But I won't be able to position that popup properly.
You can consider the example as a reaction view of WhatsApp for chat items.
